# createUserWithEmailAndPassword and handling catch with firebase.auth.Error give compilation error TS2345

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I call the following method and I want to catch the error and check the error code I can't specify the type of error other than Error type so I can't access to the error. Code from the `firebase.auth.Error`.

Methode description : 
(method) firebase.auth.Auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: string, password: string): firebase.Promise

Specifing `firebase.auth.Auth` in the then work but `firebase.auth.Error` give me a compilation error.

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(error: Error) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: Error) => any'.
Types of parameters 'error' and 'a' are incompatible.
Type 'Error' is not assignable to type 'firebase.auth.Error'.
Property 'code' is missing in type 'Error'.
```

```
this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
                .then( (auth: firebase.auth.Auth) => { return auth; } )
                .catch( (error: firebase.auth.Error) => {

                    let errorCode = error.code;
                    let errorMessage = error.message;

                    if (errorMessage === "auth/weak-password") {
                    alert("The password is too weak.");
                    } else {
                    alert(errorMessage);
                    }
                    console.log(error);

                });
```

Comment: It looks like your `error` variable is of `Error` type, where you need `firebase.auth.Error`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look in `firebase.d.ts`, you will see that `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` has this signature:

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: string, password: string): firebase.Promise<any>;
```

And `firebase.Promise` extends `firebase.Promise_Instance` which has this signature for `catch`:

```
catch(onReject?: (a: Error) => any): firebase.Thenable<any>;
```

And that's  why you are seeing an error reported by TypeScript: you cannot pass an arrow function that receives a `firebase.auth.Error`, as that contains a `code` property that's not present in`Error`.

You can cast the received `Error` to a `firebase.auth.Error` so that you can access its `code` property without a TypeScript error being effected:

```
this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
  .then((auth: firebase.auth.Auth) => { return auth; } )
  .catch((error: Error) => {

    let authError = error as firebase.auth.Error;
    let errorCode = authError.code;
    let errorMessage = authError.message;

    if (errorMessage === "auth/weak-password") {
      alert("The password is too weak.");
    } else {
      alert(errorMessage);
    }
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Also, you don't really need to specify types for the parameters in the arrow functions, as TypeScript will infer them. In fact, that's why the error was being effected in the first place.